# How to get the time life elapsed by android app with a intentservice

Tags: android, service, lifecycle, intentservice, lifetime

I need to get the lifetime elapsed for an android app with a intentservice. How can i do this in all scenarios (home button pressed | swap from recent apps | back to exit?

What i really need is send to a server the time of usage per session using Api 19

Comment: What is "lifetime elapsed for an android app"? What does an `IntentService` have to do with it?

Comment: 1.- Lifetime: is the time elapsed of the running app. From beginning of the process to the end

2.-The intentservice will help to maintain another process for detect when de app become closed

Well is just an idea. But if you have another solution is welcome